# It is best to view the thread dump with an analysis tool:

Tags: java, thread-dump

It is best to view the thread dump with an analysis tool:

```
 http://www.cubrid.org/blog/dev-platform/how-to-analyze-java-thread-dumps/
 http://java.net/projects/tda
```

A single thread dump is sometimes difficult to assess what is actually happening. Where possible multiple (5) thread dumps spaced 15 sec part should be generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this two links that provide good information on the [dumps](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yxtsPoe-beY).